# 'Item' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: react-grid-layout

I imported @material-ui/core, @devexpress/dx-react-core @devexpress/dx-react-grid and some other modules but issue is not resolving.
My App.js code:

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Can you add a bit more detail here?

Comment: did you get a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @MustafaAl-Salhi Something is not defined. Mean The definition not written in code of any component.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the example provided for the `Grid` component is a bit misleading. I just had exactly the same trouble with the `Stack` component, which suffers from the same problem.

If you use the example code as-is, it gives exactly this error because it includes `Item` elements. This gives the impression that each of your code fragments in the control needs to be wrapped in an `Item` element. Unfortunately, there is no such thing (unless you happen to define one).

So the solution is simply to exclude the `Item` elements:

```
return (
 <div className="App">
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <p>xs=8</p>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <p>xs=4</p>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <p>xs=4</p>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <p>xs=8</p>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually  definition is not there. Just place this before App() function:

```
const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));
```

It will work.

Comment: It will work, but you don't need to do that! See my answer.